# Why null value is matching the record pattern?

Tags: java, pattern-matching, record-patterns

I have been trying out examples of pattern matching with record patterns in Java 21. The official documentation asserts that a null value does not match any record pattern. However, I try this example:

```java
record Point(Integer x, Integer y) {}

public class MainPatternMatchingRecord {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printSum(new Point(null, 2));
    }

    private static void printSum(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Point(var x, var y)) {
            System.out.println(x + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Here, in my understanding of JEP, `new Point(null, 2)` shouldn't match in `instanceof Point(var x, var y)`, but when run program, throws this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot
> invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because "x" is null

Why is this behaviour happen? How should correctly interpret that null value not match any record pattern?

Comment: If `obj` was null it wouldn't match any pattern. Not sure why you think `Point(null, 2)` wouldn't.

Comment: can you please add which part of the JEP is stating that it does not match if any **field** of the record is `null`? ( `new Point(null, 2)`  definitively is **not null** )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[JEP 440](https://openjdk.org/jeps/440) indeed says:

> The null value does not match any record pattern.

But look carefully at what a record pattern is:

> A record pattern consists of a record class type and a (possibly empty) pattern list [...]

The JEP also specified the syntax of a record pattern like this:

```
Pattern:
  TypePattern
  RecordPattern

TypePattern:
  LocalVariableDeclaration

RecordPattern:
  ReferenceType ( [ PatternList ] )

PatternList : 
  Pattern { , Pattern }
```

By these definitions, we can see that `var x` and `var y` are ***not*** record patterns. They are *type patterns*. The rule that "The null value does not match any record pattern" does not apply to `var x` and `var y`.

This rule does apply to the entire `Point(var x, var y)` pattern, which *is* a record pattern, so if `obj` is null, it will not match `Point(var x, var y)`.

I can't find exactly where in the JEP says that type patterns in record patterns behave like this, but the [preview spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/preview/specs/patterns-switch-record-patterns-jls.html#jls-14.30.2) does state this explicitly:

> Consider, for example:
>
> ```
> class Super {}
> class Sub extends Super {}
> record R(Super s) {}
> ```
>
> We expect all non-null values of type `R` to match the pattern
> `R(Super s)`, including the value resulting from evaluating the
> expression `new R(null)`. (Even though the null value does not match
> the pattern `Super s`.) However, we would not expect this value to match the pattern `R(Sub s)` as the `null` value for the record component does not match the pattern `Sub s`.
>
> The meaning of a pattern occurring in a nested pattern list is then determined with respect to the record declaration. Resolution replaces any type patterns appearing in a nested pattern list that should match all values including `null` with instances of the special any pattern. In our example above, the pattern `R(Sub s)` is resolved to the pattern `R(Sub s)`, whereas the pattern `R(Super s)` is resolved to a record pattern with type `R` and a nested pattern list containing an any pattern.

In other words, `Point(var x, var y)` is resolved to `Point(<any>, <any>)`. The `<any>` pattern here can match everything, including null.

---

Here's another example:

```
record Foo(Integer x, Integer y) {}

record Bar(Foo a, Foo b) {}
```

```
private static void printSum(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Bar(Foo(Integer x1, Integer y1), Foo(var x2, var y2))) {
        System.out.println("matched!");
    }
}
```

Now, a `new Bar(null, null)` would *not* match the pattern `Bar(Foo(Integer x1, Integer y1), Foo(var x2, var y2))`, because `Foo(Integer x1, Integer y1)` is a record pattern, and `null` does not match it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand now how work Record Pattern.